# TYPO3 v12 and CKEditor 5 add own font families

Tags: fonts, icons, typo3, ckeditor

In TYPO3 v12 all assets are collected in the _assets folder. Also in the CKEditor 5 the styles definition has changed. Before it was possible to define a style with an own icons font. Now the icon font is not loaded. I guess the path is wrong.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to Composer? If it is not, please remove the tag

Answer (score 1):

To add styles to the RTE, add the following lines to your preset:

```
editor:
  config:
    # Include custom CSS
    contentsCss:
      - "/build/rte.css"
```

or

```
editor:
  config:
    # Include custom CSS
    contentsCss:
      - "EXT:my_extension/Resources/Public/Css/rte.css"
```

For a class in rte.css:

```
.myClass {
    content: "\f103";
    font-family: iconfont;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

in BE, the generated class is

```
#data_tt_content__123__bodytext_ckeditor5 .ck-content .myClass {
    content: "\f103";
    font-family: iconfont;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

where 123 is the uid of the content element.

Now, the styles are applied, but not the fonts. Since the editor is no longer loaded in an iframe, you need to load the fonts for the whole backend. Create a separate css file, with the fonts and other styles you need to apply globally:

/build/rte-fonts.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "iconfont";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url("../fonts/iconfont/iconfont.woff2?df2506553b4ceffdcf3be07cd2388757") format("woff2"),
url("../fonts/iconfont/iconfont.woff?df2506553b4ceffdcf3be07cd2388757") format("woff");
}
```

and load it in ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['stylesheets']['my_extension'] = 'build/rte-fonts.css';
```